# I want to determine the gravitational potential at $r$ from a massive planet from Laplace's Equation. Is this possible?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

It can be found from Poisson's Equation.

[Poisson's Equation can be done with Green's functions.](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node31.html)

I assume I would have to choose some appropriate B.C.s to derive that answer from Laplace.

[Solving Laplace's Equation.](http://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/chapter5/5.4.html)

Comment: Laplace's equation is for a source free region, your problem doesn't satisfy that condition as the planet is gravitational source.

Comment: So, I definitely can't get the solution from boundary conditions? That seems to imply that  if I am considering a patch of space in outer space, where Laplace's equation is valid, then there is no potential. Or Laplace's Equation doesn't apply out there because there is a source somewhere else.

Comment: I'm very confused about the meaning of "in a charge free region of space Laplace's equation holds." Does that mean in a region that encloses no charge or a region that is far away from  all charge? If the first, then it seems Laplace's equation should hold in an empty region of space .

Comment: "If there is no potential source (or sink) enclosed by S Laplace’s equation
should be applied to find the potential at a point P outside the surface S that
contains all attracting mass, for instance the potential at the location of a
satellite. But in the limit, it is also valid at the Earth’s surface." page 52 https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/earth-atmospheric-and-planetary-sciences/12-201-essentials-of-geophysics-fall-2004/lecture-notes/ch2.pdf

Comment: Is your question *why do we use Laplace equation in a region of space with no mass* ??

Comment: I understand that now. Now, I'm just wondering how you would solve Laplace's Equation in a region where there is no mass and you aren't expanding that region out to include the mass. Which I suppose comes down to determining what the B.C.s would be.

Comment: I want to know how to determine u in the region of the second figure on page 52. This is assuming I don't know anything about the mass outside the region other than the effect it is having in this region.  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/earth-atmospheric-and-planetary-sciences/12-201-essentials-of-geophysics-fall-2004/lecture-notes/ch2.pdf

Comment: Did you read my answer? I actually cite to that very article in my answer. There are various ways to solve for the potential, so you'll need to think about how you want to solve it. The boundary conditions you use depend on what kind of problem you want to solve. In that article, it gives several examples of different kinds of problems  for how to use spherical harmonics to write the solution. Please read my answer below and comment there if you have further questions about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laplace equation for gravitational potential $\phi$,
$$ \nabla^2\phi = 0\,,$$
[is the homogeneous form](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html) of the [Poisson equation](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node31.html) (in this link they use Green's functions to write the general solution),
$$ \nabla^2\phi = -4\pi G\rho$$
where $\rho$ is the mass density. So, to be blunt, when there is no mass in a region of space then $\rho = 0$ and Poisson equation becomes Laplace equation.

Depending on how you want to calculate solutions, you could use series expansions of spherical harmonics which are the general solution to the Laplace equation. This [is done](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/%7Eminote/COURSES/ph631/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=emch3_.pdf) in electrostatics, and can be done with gravity in a similar way. You may find [this](http://www-gpsg.mit.edu/12.201_12.501/BOOK/chapter2.pdf) article informative.

> I assume I would have to choose some appropriate B.C.s to derive that answer from Laplace.

Using the general solution with spherical harmonics, you must use the boundary conditions, whatever they are, to match the solutions inside and outside your surface of interest. Since you gave so few details in the OP, I can't provide more info. However, I can say that this might be overkill, and you could calculate a [simpler solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation#Newtonian_gravity).

Comment: Using bold-face $\mathbf{A}$ here implies that this is a vector equation.  Isn't $\Phi$ more customary for the gravitational potential anyhow?

Comment: Whoops! You're correct, thank you. I've fixed it.

Comment: Thanks. I see now that it's possible. If find these articles somewhat difficult.

Comment: My pleasure! It might be useful for you to work through the electrostatics problems first, maybe its closer to your intuition. http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/%7Eminote/COURSES/ph631/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=emch3_.pdf